# re-install R in ubuntu

Tags: uninstall

I have messed up R's Makeconf file. 
I tried:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove r-base
sudo apt-get --purge remove r-base-dev
```

--I got R in the first place by doing:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base
sudo apt-get install r-base-dev
```

but when I type

```
R
```

R still starts. Also the Makeconf file is still 
the one I messed up.

Comment: Can you paste the output of `which R`?  Edit: never mind.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `r-base` package is just a metapackage that also installs `r-base-core` and `r-base-recommended`. You need to remove `r-base-core` to get rid of the executable and the makeconf.

Comment: This did not for me; R is completely broken - how do I uninstall it? Purge it totally!  I would like to start again.

Comment: My packages were in `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library` -- if this directory exists, try removing that

Comment: The `.libPaths()` command in R will show all the package locations on your device.  Prior to removing R, run this command and delete these directories.  Sorry this comment is probably too little too late for many, but I hope it helps.